# Add one level to the caption numbering

Tags: numbering

I am using book class and I have an appendice section in \appendix :

```
\appendix
\include{annexes}
```

in this appendix I have several chapter and section of figures :

```
\chapter{Cartes et Plans}
\section{Ville}

\begin{figure}[ht] 
    \includegraphics{Figure 1.jpg}
    \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
    \includegraphics{Figure 1.jpg}
    \caption{Figure 2}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

\section{Section}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
    \includegraphics{figure3.JPG}
    \caption{Figure 3}
\end{figure}
```

Currently my figures are numbered as follow :

A.1 Figure 1

A.2 Figure 2

A.3 Figure 3

I would like it to be

A.1.1 Figure 1

A.1.2 Figure 2

A.2.1 Figure 3

to match with the section/chapter numbering, does anyone know if there is an easy way to do that ?

Thanks a lot for your help and apologies if a similar topic has already been answered I couldn't find it

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

Your original figure numbering - the default for `book` - is set via

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
```

which prints `<chapter>.<figure>`. Immediately after `\appendix`, you can issue

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
```

which will print `<chapter>.<section>.<figure>` as the figure number.

Here's a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A regular figure}
\end{figure}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

\chapter{An appendix chapter}

\section{First section}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{First figure}

  \medskip

  \caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Next section}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Final figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is quick and efficient, thank you Werner